# Jquery go to this href

Tags: jquery

How can I say that if it is a touch device do not hover and go direct to click?
Here is the example to play: http://jsfiddle.net/2Sax4/4/

The key point is how to say to get the a href. Something like this:

```
window.location= 'http://' + this a;
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    // not touch:      
    $(".menu li").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({ "background-color":red }, 1000);
    },function() {
        $(this).animate({ "background-color":blue }, 1000);
    });

    // touch:
    var supportsTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window || 'onmsgesturechange' in window;
    if(supportsTouch) {
        $(this).on('touchstart', function(){
                    //I tried something like this
            window.location= 'http://' + this a;  
        }); 

    }   
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="first"><a href="first.html">first</a></li>
    <li id="second"><a href="second.html">second</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I had an important error in the question and the fiddle. I had: $(this).hover(function() and I update to: $(".menu li").hover(function()

Comment: The "not touch" effect is not appreciated in the fiddle. I think the jquery ui is not possible to load it or I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.location.href = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/' + $( 'a', this).prop('href');
```

if you don't know the protocol or the host (hostname + port).

Comment: I think you mean  `$('a', this)` instead and using the property would not work in this case.

Comment: @Felix : i made the change

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
window.location= $("a", this).attr("href");
```

Of course, this would work if `this` refers to the `li`, which I think from your code, it does.

Comment: I think you mean `$("a", this)` instead.

Comment: I don't know though if the browser would be able to redirect to the right page if you assign e.g. `http://first.html` (which is what you are currently doing).

Comment: You can assign computed values for `window.location`.

Comment: That's not what I meant. You are basically assigning `http://first.html` because the `href` attribute contains `first.html`. But `http://first.html` looks like as if  `first.html` is the host, instead of being the file. The URL should be `http://<host of current page>/<path of current page>/first.html`.

Comment: I see what you mean. A better way would be just to remove the protocol. Updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

what is $(this) in this case? generally, you could do:

`window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');` assuming $(this) is the `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps:

1. Get the a reference to the `a` element.
2. Assign the proper URL to `window.location.href`.

To get a reference to the link, you just have to find it in the element's descendants:

```
var link = $(this).find('a'); // or $(this).children('a');
```

Now, while the `href` HTML attribute only contains part of the URL (the file name), the corresponding *DOM property* contains a *complete* URL (scheme, host, path, etc), based on the current URL of the page.
So we can just take it and assign it to `window.location/href`:

```
window.location.href = link.prop('href');
```